# .NET wcf service output

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have the following web service interface.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://customnamespacehere")]
public interface IDebtKnowledge
{
    [OperationContract]
    SubscriberOutput GetSubscribers(SubscriberInput subscriberInput);

}
```

It generates output below. But I want to generate it without **v1:GetSubscribers** tag. Its my method name.

```
   <soapenv:Body>
  <v1:GetSubscribers>
     <v1:subscriberInput>
        <akt:IpAddress>?</akt:IpAddress>
        <akt:OperatorCode>?</akt:OperatorCode>
        <akt:Password>?</akt:Password>
        <akt:Username>?</akt:Username>           
     </v1:subscriberInput>
  </v1:GetSubscribers>
```

How can I get output below?

```
   <soapenv:Body>
     <v1:subscriberInput>
        <akt:IpAddress>?</btk:IpAddress>
        <akt:OperatorCode>?</btk:OperatorCode>
        <akt:Password>?</akt:Password>
        <akt:Username>?</akt:Username>
     </v1:subscriberInput>      
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I marked my SubscriberInput class and all parent class with

```
[DataContract]
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
```

then I got this exception.

```
The operation 'GetSubscribers' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with ssageContractAttribute,  the method must not use any other types of parameters.
```

Comment: You dont want method name? Why?

Comment: Because my client wants like this.

Comment: Then how about operationcontract like SubscriberOutput subscriberInput(IpAddress,OperatorCode,Password,UserName);

Comment: Define message contract and set IsWrapped=false attribute on it.

Comment: @PankajKapare I defined on class name but it does not work

Comment: Is that class marked as message contract?

Comment: Yes I marked : [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after adding the following tags in my returning class.

```
[DataContract]
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
```